# Specifying default theme in Eclipse product doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, photon

I'm trying to create an Eclipse 4.8 application and defining the theme with the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

I'd like to have the dark theme that bundled with `org.eclipse.ui.theme_1.2.100` be the default.

I see this in the plugin XML:

```
   <stylesheet
         uri="css/dark/e4-dark_preferencestyle.css">
      <themeid
            refid="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_dark"></themeid>
   </stylesheet>
```

I'm specifying my product like this:

```
<plugin>
   <extension id="ide" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" name="%productName" description="%productName">
         <property name="introTitle" value="%introTitle" />
         <property name="applicationCSSResources" value="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/images/" />
         <property name="applicationXMI" value="org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi" />
         <property name="cssTheme" value="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_dark" />
         <property name="preferenceCustomization" value="plugin_customization.ini" />
      </product>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

But when I build and launch the application, it seems to still be the default light theme. Am I defining the css properly?

Comment: `applicationCSSResources` should be `platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.themes/images/`

Comment: Make sure you have your plugin_customization on the build path, make sure in your .product file you have that theme plugin to autostart, still not working make sure you can go to preferences and set it manually to see if the plugin is loaded. my two cents